# How to check if a var stored '#' or any special char

Tags: python-3.x

A simple code like this:

```
for input in sys.stdin:
    if input=='#': break .   #this is considered false even if I type # and wont break
    print(input)             #it prints #
```

I want the user to type # to stop the loop, but even if I type #, the statement is still considered false.

It's not just '#' but also '!' or '@' etc.

Does anyone know why? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked for the reason, I think its actually the break line you add at the end of your input. if you use this code it actually works:

```
import sys

for input in sys.stdin:
    input = input.strip()
    if input=='#': 
        break
    print(input)
```

Here you can see that the breakline is in the string:

```
import sys
for user_input in sys.stdin.detach():
    print(user_input)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I understand there are many other solution to this, but I mainly wanna know why input!='#'

Comment: finally figured it out thanks to you. I just modified my code to    if input=='#\n'  then it works just like that :D

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to get input from a user is with the `input` function:

```
inp = input('Type something')
if inp!='#': 
  print(inp)
```

Running with input that is anything other than `#` will echo the input back to you, otherwise it will do nothing (`break` as you put, however this will not work as it is outside of a loop)

Comment: for some reason I had to use sys.stdin which I believe returns a string. It's driving me crazy wondering why input!='#'

Answer (score 0):

```
for something in sys.stdin:
    ...
```

The code above does not work as you expect because sys.stdin is a file handle and it will not reach the some '...'.

But you can use the code below and it will break as you would expect:

```
inp = input('Write here:')
if inp!='#': 
  print(inp)
```